# Prove or disprove this ? $\sin(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1}+z(e\pi+1))\neq0$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, irrational-numbers

> Prove or disprove this :
> $\forall (k.m)\in \mathbb Z^*\times\mathbb Z^*, \text{and } (z,r,s)\in \mathbb N\times\mathbb N^*\times\mathbb N^*\text{ where } 1\leq r <s$:
> $$\sin(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1}+z(e\pi+1))\neq0$$

**My atempt**:

for $z=0$ : $$\sin(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1}+z(e\pi+1))=\sin(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1})\neq0$$
Because $$:k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1}\neq a\pi ,\quad a\in \mathbb Z $$
for $z>0$ :
\begin{align*}
\sin(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1}+z(e\pi+1))&=\sin(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1})\cos(ze\pi+z)-\sin(ze\pi+z)\cos(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1})\\
&=\sin(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1})\sqrt{1-\sin^2(ze\pi+z)}-\sin(ze\pi+z)\sqrt{1-\sin^2(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1})}\\
&=\sin(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1})\times\alpha_1-\alpha_2\times\alpha_3\\
\end{align*}
where:$\{_{\alpha_1=\sqrt{1-\alpha_2^2}}^{\alpha_2=\sin(z(e\pi+1))}$
and
$\alpha_3=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1})}$

After the calculation, I found that this is true
$$\sin(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1})\neq0$$
If this is true
$$ \sin(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1})\neq \sqrt{\alpha_2^2(\alpha_3^2+\sin^2(k\pi^{r+1}+m\pi^{s+1})}$$
But now I have no idea to prove this،
I posted this question in order to find a suggestion of an idea or a guess about proving this if possible to help me. Thanks in advance .

Comment: You did not say what $e$ is.  If it is the base of the natural logarithms, this problem seems hopeless to me.  If $e$ is an integer, then the problem should be easy, using the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 1}e^x$